# SQL Create a new calculated column based on values of multi rows and cols

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I have a data about airline's booking, using Oracle db, sample is structured as below:

[image: Data sample]

- Recordlocator is booking code
- Sequencenmbr: whenever there is a change in booking, it records new status of a booking with higher Sequencenmbr. So the highest Sequencenmbr in the database shows the latest/current status of bookings
- Sequenceair: is the sequence of flights in bookings, it may be one or many flights in a booking
- DepartAirport: is from airport
- ArrAirport: is to airport.

So the question is, I  would like to create new Itinerary column that shows full Itinerary of booking in every rows, which is combination of DepartAirport of each row (in order of SequenceAir) and ArrAirport of a last row. Could anyone help me with the SQL statement or give some links to read?

It has to group by Recordlocator, Sequencenmbr and order by SequenceAir. It should look like this:

[image: result]

| Recordlocator | Sequencenmbr | SequenceAir | DepartureDateTime | DepartAirport | ArrAirport | Itinerary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GQWYGM | 32 | 1 | 25/11/18 16:40 | RGN | SIN | RGN-SIN-JKT-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 32 | 2 | 26/11/18 09:35 | SIN | JKT | RGN-SIN-JKT-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 32 | 3 | 29/11/18 06:50 | JKT | SIN | RGN-SIN-JKT-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 32 | 4 | 29/11/18 11:00 | SIN | RGN | RGN-SIN-JKT-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 33 | 1 | 25/11/18 16:40 | RGN | SIN | RGN-SIN-MNL-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 33 | 2 | 26/11/18 09:35 | SIN | MNL | RGN-SIN-MNL-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 33 | 3 | 29/11/18 06:50 | MNL | SIN | RGN-SIN-MNL-SIN-RGN |
| GQWYGM | 33 | 4 | 29/11/18 11:00 | SIN | RGN | RGN-SIN-MNL-SIN-RGN |

Manythanks

Comment: 1. please do not use images for sample data, put this into you post. 2. what do you try so far?

Comment: @droebi this is quite hard for a newbie like me. I cannot see what you mean by "put this". I have no idea how to deal with this problem as well as I found nothing that can help. Therefore I had to put my 1st question in the community.

Comment: Is the image with result correct? It shows the same values as data sample with the excption of 2 and 3 row -> JTK instead od NML

Comment: Maybe read the HowToDos in SO Meta, this is helpful and you will get quicker good answers if you follow the recommendations: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @OjtamOjtam oh sorry, I have change the result picture, pls help check

Comment: The first comment means that YOU SHOULD PUT THE EXAMPLE AS TEXT IN THE QUESTIONS and NOT USE PICTURES

Comment: What SQL platform are you using MS SQL, mysql, DB2, Oracle or something else?

Comment: @Hogan I'm using Oracle, and thanks for your help, I already edited my post. Hope it looks OK now.

Comment: The example input is **still** a picture, **not** text.

Comment: @RyanM actually it's included in result that I see no need to change. It's just the result without Itinerary column. Thanks for ur suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Recordlocator , Sequencenmbr, Sequenceair , DepartAirport, ArrAirport, departureDateTime
     , LISTAGG(
           (
             case 
                when last_arrAirport = DepartAirport then arrAirport -- removes duplicates when last arrival and current departure are the same
                else DepartAirport||'-'||ArrAirport
             end
           )
       ,'-') 
       WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SequenceAir) -- order by
         OVER (PARTITION BY Recordlocator, Sequencenmbr) list -- group by
 from (
      select taskStack.* -- all data from your table
          ,  lag(ArrAirport) over (PARTITION BY Recordlocator, Sequencenmbr -- group by
                                   order by Recordlocator,Sequencenmbr,Sequenceair) last_arrAirport -- arrAirport from previous row
        from taskStack
 ) 
 order BY Recordlocator,Sequencenmbr,Sequenceair
```

Comment: oh Jesus, It's miracle. I would never do that myself. It solves the problem. Hence it's so difficult to use every time, is there any way to make it a permanent computed column to the table, or make some kind of function so that we can simply call its name every time we need

Comment: you can change this into a view -- then just join to the view @VietAnhNguyen  If you do please don't use `taskStack.*` -- use a column list - using * is bad practice except in ad-hoc queries.

Comment: thank @Hogan for the idea. I will create a view with this calculated column and few other columns so that I can join this view later

Answer (score 0):

You should use LISTAGG to do this

```
LISTAGG(DepartAirport||'-'||ArrAirport,'-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SequenceAir)
```

in your select statement.

Comment: I have read LISTAGG and I saw it would group the table while I wish to repeat in all relative rows. And it doesn't always combine departAirport with ArrAirport. To be precise, it combine DepartAirport of each row and ArrAirport of thet last row.
Anyway, I run and get this error:

[Error] Execution (1: 8): ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
select Recordlocator, Sequencenmbr, SequenceAir, DEPARTDATETIME, DEPARTAIRPORTAIR, ARRAIRPORTAIR, LISTAGG(DEPARTAIRPORTAIR||'='||ARRAIRPORTAIR,'-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY SequenceAir) as Itinerary
from itdev.v_booking_seg

Comment: @VietAnhNguyen --- check out OjtamOjtam's answer -- it much better than my answer as it takes care of edge case issues.